# ERROR: "unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"

Tags: php, codeigniter

My CodeIgniter project runs well on localhost but when I uploaded it on live server produce some errors like this:

> ERROR: "unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"

in this part of code:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');                        $flag = 0;

            $data = $this->user_model->Signup_user((
                'username' => $username
                'email' => $email
                'password' => $password
                'flag' => $flag
                ));
```

Comment: the array element must be separated by a comma 'username' => $username, 
                'email' => $email  , and so on

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$password = $this->input->post('password');                        
$flag = 0;

$data = $this->user_model->Signup_user(
    array(
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    'flag' => $flag,
    )
);
```

You need to pass array with all the values but you were using wrong syntax for that.

Comment: You should explain why it doesn't work, so the OP can understand what was wrong.

Comment: sorry about that, have added explanation. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, just make it easier for the OP to learn from his mistakes.

Comment: Thanks it is working